# how to submit data to my database when the paypal buynow button is clicked from my cart

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

hi there Iam creating a Paypal IPN and i have a pay now button in my cart page which is of type image. Im used to using type submit. i was just wondering how i would write to my database on the submition of this pay now button. what i mean is i want to write to the database as this button is clicked but im not sure exactly how to do it? here is my code for sending my data to paypal.

```
<?php


 if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['itemnames']))
   {
   $checkoutbutton .='<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgibin/webscr"     method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
     <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxx">
     <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">';

  ?> <ul2>

   <?php


  for ($i = 0;$i <count($_SESSION['itemnames']);$i++)
     { ?>
          <li>

         <?php
         $x = $i + 1;
        echo "<h3>";
        echo $_SESSION['itemnames'][$i];   
        echo "</h3>";
        echo "<b>Cost per Item:  &euro;" .$_SESSION['price'][$i] ."</br> Number of Items: " . $_SESSION['quantity'][$i] ."</b>";


        $checkoutbutton .='<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$x.'" value="'. $_SESSION['itemnames'][$i] .'">  
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$x.'" value="' .$_SESSION['price'][$i] . '">
        <input type="hidden" name="quantity_'.$x.'" value="' .$_SESSION['quantity'][$i] . '">';
          ?>

         </li>
         <?php }      $checkoutbutton .='<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://ipnscript.php">
                                         <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://ranscomplete.php">
                                         <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
                                         <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="return to store">
                                         <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.theislandapp.com/transcancelled.php">
                                         <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                       <input type="image" src="x-click-but5.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!">';

          ?>   

          </ul2> 


               <?php }

              else {?>
              <h2> No Items in cart </h2>
            <?php } ?> </br></br>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to store in your db?

Comment: ill explain further. usually i have a input type submit surrounded by a form and i have the form method as post and i use if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { //i get it to do something }

Comment: oh i dont have the db stuff in there yet was just wondering how i would go about sending to db as button is clicked?

Comment: could i just put another form around the button and post it to this same page. or is there somewhere else where i should be sending the data to the database apart from the cart page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a step before heading to PayPal. Basically your cart would POST to another script on your site, which would log whatever info you need, and then you can loop through your cart and send things over to PayPal via a GET string on the URL. I believe the variables are the same, plus you can even get their name and address info to store on your side beforehand.

Comment: its this other step that your talking about which im not quite sure how to implement! or even where to start. this shopping cart is hard

Comment: @eoin your form should submit not on paypal website, but on your own script that will write the data into the database and then fire for paypal.

Comment: so from what ive been reading it seems that i should ad the items to the database as the items are added to the cart! seems strange as the client buying the stuff might add stuff to the cart delete it again or even just leave the page all together!

Comment: yes what i want to be able to do is send relevant data to myself when paypal buy now is pressed in the cart and then post to paypal not sure how to do this at the same time

Comment: alright i think i ahve an idea for how to do this properly when the user goes to view cart i will persist to the databasewith a unique id i will create as a session variable. if the user goes back and decides to add another item to the cart i will delete the original items in the database using the unique session id and add the new values to the database then my ipn can do checks and if all are cleared i will mark the items associated with that id as paid! god damn i really have to rework this thing before i hand it in next wednesday, might be pulling a few all nighters yet!

Comment: or can i use a POST and a GET on the same stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use ajax(jquery) to call a page in the background, it doesn't even have to display any data.

```
$.post("save.php", { name: "John", item: "143" } );
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

By giving your buy button an id, and using click function would make this possible.

```
<input id="yebeclicked" type="image" src="x-click-but5.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!">
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#yebeclicked").click(function() {
 $.post("save.php", { name: "John", item: "143" } );
});
</script>
```

Cheers. ;)